# Authenticated onto two seperate sites with one login (and using an IFrame). Possible?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iframe, cookies

Currently building a site in ASP.NET MVC and have to integrate another site within it, in an IFrame. It is the wish of the client to have one login for both systems, so the user logs in in the parent site, and then are automatically authenticated on the IFramed site. Of course, if this were possible then it could be assumed that both sets of login credentials were the same. So, it there anyway this can be done easily?

Its worth noting that we don't have any real control over the IFramed site. Its basically a site that our client provide their customers for processing payments.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I suppose OpenID or WS*-Federation is out of the question?)

If the credentials are the same, couldn't you simply submit the credentials to the iframe before you submit your own login form?

Or if you want to check credentials first, then send them to your server, check return them back to the client as a javascript snippet that then does the iframe authentication. (But be aware you would be sending **credentials** back to the client **as javascript**.)

An example that might work for you:

Say your login Url is http://yourdomain/login and you also need to login to http://thirdparty/login

yourdomain/login wants two post variables "username" and "pwd" whereas thirdparty/login wants "uname" and "password".

Try to include jQuery in your project (there are ways to do it in javascript by itself, but you'll have to check what jQuery does in the background - but I strongly suggest not reinventing the wheel if you don't have to).

```
// this is the jQuery startup function, called once the page is loaded
$(function()
{
    // register an event for the form submit
    $("form[@action*='login']").submit(function(event){  
        // get username and pwd from the form
        var _user = $("#username").val();
        var _password = $("#pwd").val();

        // and submit to the second login page
        $.post("http://thirdparty/login", { user: _user, password: _password } );

        // once the method returns and you don't do return false then the login form     will be submitted as usual.
    });  

});
```

There may be one issue here that is that you are posting to a different url than the server that served the page. This may not be allowed, but you could bypass it by sending the post action of the original login page to the thirdparty page and login to your own system using the code above.

Reference:
JQuery Post: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post
JQuery Intercept Form Submit: http://blog.james-carr.org/2008/01/17/jquery-binding-submit-on-a-forms-action-attribute/

Comment: yep - no openid here. the site we are hosting in an iframe is rather old to say the least.

thanks for your advice. would you be able to provide any more details on how I would go about sumbitting credentials to the iframe? would that have to be done via javascript (bit of a noob here)

Comment: added an example for reference